# How to bind to the page from a child of a custom control

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have the following custom Silverlight breadcrumb control:

```
    <custom:BreadcrumbList Navigator="{Binding ModuleNavigator}">
        <custom:BreadcrumbList.Items>
            <custom:BreadcrumbItem ViewName="Home"/>
            <custom:BreadcrumbItem ViewName="Items"/>
            <custom:BreadcrumbItem Command="{Binding ReturnCommand}"/>
            <custom:BreadcrumbItem ViewName="ItemConstraints"/>
        </custom:BreadcrumbList.Items>
    </custom:BreadcrumbList>
```

I would really like the `Command` property of the `BreadcrumbItem` to bind to *the data context of the* page not the parent control. I know how to do this in other XAML environments with the `RelativeSource` binding argument, but that doesn't work here. How might i do this in Silverlight?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, I'm still waiting for a better one. `BreadcrumbItem` subclasses directly `DependencyObject`. I added the following property to it:

```
    private Object _parentContext = null;

    public Object ParentContext
    {
        get { return _parentContext; }
        set { _parentContext = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ParentContext"); }
    }
```

Then in the `Loaded` event of the `BreadcrumbList` (parent control) I set all of the items `ParentContext` property to the its data context.

```
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= OnLoaded;

        foreach (var item in Items.OfType<BreadcrumbItem>())
            item.ParentContext = DataContext;
    }
```

Then I changed my XAML to be:

```
<custom:BreadcrumbList Navigator="{Binding ModuleNavigator}">
    <custom:BreadcrumbList.Items>
        <custom:BreadcrumbItem ViewName="Home"/>
        <custom:BreadcrumbItem ViewName="Items"/>
        <custom:BreadcrumbItem Command="{Binding ParentContext.ReturnCommand}"/>
        <custom:BreadcrumbItem ViewName="ItemConstraints"/>
    </custom:BreadcrumbList.Items>
</custom:BreadcrumbList>
```

This works, but I'm still looking for a better option.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways depending on what level your datacontext is. If you are binding to an element in a datagrid per se then you can use a binding to relative source with an ancestor type of what ever your parent control type is. 
If you have a specific element that has the data you are looking for you can binding using that element name and path to the data.
If you have a view model declared in your xaml you can bind to a static resource and use the name of the view model and path to the data item.

Comment: Two of those do not work in Silverlight.  The other one doesn't really help me. I'm trying to get to the page's data context (my view model) from within an inner element (i.e. `BreadcrumbItem`).  Thanks anyway.